# jquery do something after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code that is executed when doing a mouseenter on a div :

```
$('.expandable').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.links').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    $(this).find('.links').show('fast', function () {
        $(this).find('.links').css('visibility', 'visible');
        alert("The paragraph is now visible");
    });
}
```

Normally `$(this).find('.links').eq(0).css('background-color', 'visible');` should be executed after the animation is done but i am looking in the developer tools (chrome) when doing mouseenter and mouseout, but the css does not change... But I am getting the alert when the animation is done.

Somebody can help me with this?

**EDIT, SOLUTION:**

```
$('.expandable').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.links').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    $(this).find('.links').show('fast', function () {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
        alert("The paragraph is now visible");
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you show us how do you trigger mouseenter/mouseout events ?

Comment: It's faster to get the element ones, something like `$('.divname').css('hello').show('fast')`

Comment: WTF? `.css('background-color', 'visible')`?

Comment: @dotweb please refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see `$(this).find('.links').eq(0).css('background-color', 'visible');` in your code. Anways you can use `this` inside the callback which will point to the element being animated. Try this.

```
$('.expandable').mouseenter(function () {
    $(".divname").css('visibility', 'hidden');

    $(".divname").fadeIn('fast', function () {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
        alert("The paragraph is now visible");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.show()` toggles `display` and `opacity` but not `visbility`.

Setting the `opacity` to 0 will have the same visual effect like settings `visbility` to `hidden`. So I suggest you it like this:

```
$(".divname").css('opacity', '0');
// In case you have no code in between those two jQuery calls, you should use chaining
$(".divname").show('fast', function () {
    $(".divname").css('visibility', 'visible');
    alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use die css attribute display. Or the funktion .hide()

Method 1:

```
$(".divname").css('display', 'none');

$(".divname").show('fast', function () {
    $(".divname").hide("fast");
    alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
});
```

Method 2:

```
$(".divname").hide("fast");

$(".divname").show('fast', function () {
    $(".divname").hide("fast");
    alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery.show doens't handle the visibility, it handles the display property. Generally, you don't want to be mixing display und visibility. Anyhow, what you are looking for is opacity=0 (has the same effect as visibility=hidden).

What I think you might want to be doing is following;

```
$('.expandable').mouseenter(function () {
    $(".divname").
                  css('opacity', 0).
                  animate(
                      {opacity:1},
                      1000,
                      "linear",
                      function(){
                          alert("the paragraph is now visible");
                      }
                  );
});
```

hope I helped